# Same keyboard layout is different on different computers

Tags: keyboard-layout

Recently I received a computer istalled with Ubuntu 18.04.06 LTS which I cannot reinstall fresh.

When I set the keyboard layout to `Slovak`, I get this:

[image: Slovak layout on new PC]

That is something entirely different than what I'm used to. Apart from having to press AltGr instead of Shift to type numbers, completely different symbol mappings, this keyboard is QWERTY. Plain `Slovak` should be QWERTZ. For QWERTY there are `Slovak QWERTY` options. That means there is no way for me to select a Slovak QWERTZ layout on that computer, all choices result in QWERTY letter layout.

This is what I expect when I select the `Slovak` layout:
[image: Expected Slovak layout, from my personal PC]
This is a screenshot from my personal Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS computer. Also when I type in `Slovak` layout on other computers, this is the familiar behavior.

How could this happen? What can I do about it?
I tried removing and then re-adding Slovak language in the "Install languages" dialog, did not help.

`setxkbmap -query -v 10`:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,sk,us
variant:    ,,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+sk:2+us:3+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,sk,us
variant:    ,,
```

`cat /etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us,sk
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=,
```

Comment: Installed languages are independent of keyboard layouts. You need to open Keyboards > Input... to add/remove layouts.

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/master/symbols/sk) is the Slovak XKB symbols file, so yes, it's your 20.04 machine which behaves as expected. If you want help so sort it out for your 18.04 machine, you need to provide more info including keyboard hardware. Also please edit your question and show us the output of these commands: `setxkbmap -query -v 10` and `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson added the requested command output

Comment: @RadovanBezak: You didn't mention which keyboard you are using. My thought is that some other keyboard model but `pc105` may be needed. To give that theory a try, you can run this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous user apparently replaced `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sk` with a different file, a modified layout supposed to be better suited for programming than the original Slovak layout. Instead of following a more complicated procedure to add this as a separate layout choice, they just replaced the original one.

Fixed by restoring the original file, since no one else will be using this computer right now.